# Using a CMYK .psd file with The Gimp

Tags: linux, gimp, psd

Is there a way to convert CMYK .psd files to an RGB .psd or to an .xcf (gimp format) on a linux computer (and without photoshop)?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223038/using-a-cmyk-psd-without-photoshop) had no answers that helped me.  XnView (installed in Wine) does not output psd or xcf files. Other solutions involved creating many png files (one for each layer), which is not ideal.  Online conversion tools I found do not accept large files.  The ghostscript plugin for gimp does not help.  I found a windows computer with 2 GB ram and installed paint.net with the psd plugin, but there was not enough memory to open the 64 MB file. Imagemagick (convert input.psd -colorspace rgb output.psd) created a file unreadable by gimp (openoffice could read it though).

Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: What happened with `convert input.psd output.xcf`?

Comment: opening in gimp gives error: “Procedure ‘file-psd-load’ returned no return values”.  http://www.openmutual.org/2011/08/converting-cmyk-psd-files-for-use-in-gimp/ says that this will happen, so it is a known limitation of convert.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to open it in Krita. Krita supports CMYK color-space natively and also it has psd import support. I can't test it for you as I don't have psd file with CMYK around.

Comment: I've opened a .psd file of about 26 Mb in Size (6761 x 2423 pixels) in Krita version 2.8.1 with KDE version 4.13.3 in Ubuntu Linux 14.04. It is necessary to convert the color space from CMYK to RGB before Krita is able to store the image as a PNG file.  Afterwards I was able to open the resulting PNG with gimp and all colours were converted in a reasonable way as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the 'separate' plugin for gimp?  Arch link as it's pretty informative and complete:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CMYK_support_in_The_GIMP#About_CMYK_color_and_Gimp

the GEGL version of gimp should improve CMYK support and other bitdepths (than 8) and is scheduled for 2.10.  This will eliminate the need for a plugin.